# Reading from USB with a listener - Boost Asio C++

Tags: c++, boost, usb, boost-asio

I'm trying to read from the USB using Boost Asio. I have no problems with writing to the USB. I have problems with reading from the USB.

My process of reading a response from an USB unit is simple.

1. Start the Boost Asio Time Out listener
2. Write a message (Here I assume that my USB device will send a response back directly)
3. Read the response data

First I have my holder for the USB port

```
static boost::asio::io_context io;
static std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::serial_port>> devicesCDC;
static std::vector<uint8_t> dataCDC;
```

My start up for the Boost Asio Time Out listener

```
void timeOut(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode) {
    std::cout << errorCode.message() << std::endl;
    std::cout << errorCode.what() << std::endl;
    std::cout << errorCode.value() << std::endl;
    if (boost::system::errc::success == errorCode) {
        std::cout << "Nothing wrong at time out" << std::endl;
    }
}

void readMessage(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytesTransferred) {
    std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
    std::cout << error.what() << std::endl;
    std::cout << error.value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << bytesTransferred << std::endl;
    if (boost::system::errc::success == error) {
        std::cout << "Nothing wrong at the reading" << std::endl;
    }
}

// Create timer
boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io, std::chrono::milliseconds(timeOutMilliseconds));

// Read
devicesCDC.at(port)->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(dataCDC), readMessage);

// Start asynkron timer
timer.async_wait(timeOut);

// Run
io.run();
```

My write process

```
auto writeHandler = [&](const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, std::size_t bytesTransferred) {};
devicesCDC.at(port)->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, length), writeHandler);
```

And the USB connection process

```
void Connect_To_USB(const char port[], const unsigned int baudrate, const unsigned int dataBits, const unsigned int flowControl, const unsigned int stopBits, const unsigned int parity) {
    // Open connection
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::serial_port> addDevice = std::make_shared<boost::asio::serial_port>(io, port);

    // Baudrate options
    addDevice->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port::baud_rate(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baudrate)));

    // Data bits options
    addDevice->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port::character_size(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(dataBits)));

    // Control flow options
    boost::asio::serial_port::flow_control controlFlowNone(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none);
    boost::asio::serial_port::flow_control controlFlowSoftware(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::software);
    boost::asio::serial_port::flow_control controlFlowHardware(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::hardware);
    switch (flowControl) {
    case USB_CONTROL_FLOW_ENUM_NONE:
        addDevice->set_option(controlFlowNone);
        break;
    case USB_CONTROL_FLOW_ENUM_SOFTWARE:
        addDevice->set_option(controlFlowSoftware);
        break;
    case USB_CONTROL_FLOW_ENUM_HARDWARE:
        addDevice->set_option(controlFlowHardware);
        break;
    default:
        addDevice->set_option(controlFlowNone);
        break;
    }

    // Stop bits options
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits stop_bits_one(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one);
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits stop_bits_onepointfive(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::onepointfive);
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits stop_bits_two(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::two);
    switch (stopBits) {
    case USB_STOP_BITS_ENUM_ONE:
        addDevice->set_option(stop_bits_one);
        break;
    case USB_STOP_BITS_ENUM_TWO:
        addDevice->set_option(stop_bits_two);
        break;
    default:
        addDevice->set_option(stop_bits_one);
        break;
    }

    // Parity options
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity parity_none(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::none);
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity parity_odd(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::odd);
    boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity parity_even(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::even);
    switch (parity) {
    case USB_PARITY_ENUM_NONE:
        addDevice->set_option(parity_none);
        break;
    case USB_PARITY_ENUM_ODD:
        addDevice->set_option(parity_odd);
        break;
    case USB_PARITY_ENUM_EVEN:
        addDevice->set_option(parity_even);
        break;
    default:
        addDevice->set_option(parity_none);
        break;
    }

    // Store the addDevice
    devicesCDC[port] = addDevice;
```

So the writing process is working, but not the reading process.
If i start a synchronous(Blocking) reading, then I can read. But when I start a event listener for readiny using asynchronous(Non blocking), then no data will be read. I get no errors from the time out and the read function.

**So my question is**

Have I miss some steps when I called

```
io.run();
```

?